# Problems following Diesel getting started guide with sqlite

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am trying to follow the diesel getting started guide - https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started

The only difference is that I am using sqlite and a file in my local directory. The DATABASE_URL value is set correctly in the env file.

DATABASE_URL=/Users/username/Sandbox/diesel_demo/diesel_demo.db

The file diesel_demo.db also exists.

When running write_post.rs I get the error:

thread 'main' panicked at 'Error connecting to /Users/username/Sandbox/diesel_demo/diesel_demo.db', src/lib.rs:15:63

Comment: Please provide a [mre] inside of the post, only linking to external resources is not sufficient for several reasons.